# Grouping and deleting repetitive elements from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list like this:

```
my_list = [ 
    [1, 'green', 'orange', 'blue']
    [2, 'orange', 'black']
    [1, 'green', 'pink' ]
    [3, 'white']
    [2, 'purple', 'yellow', 'black']
]
```

So, I need to have another list from my_list like this:

```
output_list = [ 
    [1, 'green', 'orange', 'blue', 'pink']
    [2, 'orange', 'black', 'purple', 'yellow']
    [3, 'white']
]
```

Is there an efficient way to do it having a count my_list is very large? I mean wich approach should be better instead of using two nested for loops? I do not expect some code, just ideas!

Thx.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just use a `dict` mapping the first element in each sublist to (a set of) the remaining elements, then turn back into a list.

Comment: It is often a good idea to delete your question while you edit to prevent spam downvotes. Please reupload when you've added examples of what you've tried already, and why it isn't working.

Comment: Hey @TigerhawkT3, mind if I save the that comment to my AutoReviewComments bank?

Comment: Ok, I accepted suggestions. My idea to do it is code two for loops but in advance I know is not a efficient way. @TigerhawkT3, I do not expect you write the code just to say to me what approach is better. My question was if there any efficient way to do it, I do not expect the code. Thx.

Comment: @FernandoBarraza the suggestion from tobias_k is likely to be the most efficient. both `set()` and `dict()` use [key hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_tables) to speed up access

Comment: @leaf - Feel free - I'm not the first person to use it, and you won't be the last. :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because There is no attempt to solve the problem shown in post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stated in the comments that tobias_k's suggestion was likely to be the most efficient, but never provided any code... here is what I would do:

```
out = {} #output dictionary can be converted back to a list later
for item in my_list:  #for each sublist
    k = item[0] #first item is our dict key
    l = item[1:] #rest of the list is data
    new = out.get(k, set()) #get whatever is at out[k] or return an empty set if nothing is there yet
    new.update(l) #add the items from l (sets will automatically trash duplicates)
    out[k] = new #set out[k] to our newly updated set
```

Comment: your code don't build the output list as I expected. Anyway, I was thinking how to use a dict function (the built-in one) but I don't know yet how to use it, because a dict with the first element as key and color names like values would have duplicated keys, I mean same key for different color names. Actually, I'm dismissing to use the dict.

Comment: I'm so sorry @Aaron, your code works well. I made a mistake trying before. Thx.

Comment: no problemo, I was gone over the weekend, but I could have given an example of how to convert back to a list initially...

Answer (score 4):

```
my_list = [ 
    [1, 'green', 'orange', 'blue'],
    [2, 'orange', 'black'],
    [1, 'green', 'pink' ],
    [3, 'white'],
    [2, 'purple', 'yellow', 'black']
]

values = set(map(lambda x:x[0], my_list))
newlist = [[x] + list(set(sum([y[1:] for y in my_list if y[0] == x], []))) for x in values]
print newlist
```

**How does it work?**

`set(map(lambda x:x[0], my_list)` creates a set containing `[1, 2, 3]` - the first elements of each list in `my_list`.

Then, we take each value of `values` using `[___ for x in values]`.

For each value in values we iterate through `my_list` and add all the lists that the `0`th element is equal to `x`. (Except for the `0`th element itself, of course)

Then, we have a list of lists of lists:

```
[[['green', 'orange', 'blue'], ['green', 'pink']], [['orange', 'black'], ['purple', 'yellow', 'black']], [['white']]]
```

So we concatenate each 3rd dimension list using `sum(the_list, [])`.

And then we want to remove duplicates, so:

```
list(set(sum(the_list, [])))
```

And we end up with:

```
[list(set(sum([y[1:] for y in my_list if y[0] == x], []))) for x in values]
```

And the only thing left is to add the first element (`x` itself) to any sublist, so

```
[[x] + ... for x in values]
```

**And we finally get:**

```
[[x] + list(set(sum([y[1:] for y in my_list if y[0] == x], []))) for x in values]
```

Comment: If you use Python 3, you should change `print` statement to `print()` function.

Comment: @MaxLunar It's not the major part of the question... Just for debugging. And I think that's pretty clear anyways

Comment: @YotamSalmon I would suggest unrolling your one liner a bit for the newbie... +1 for detailed explanation, but the code itself could have been simpler in the first place. this isn't [ppcg](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) :P

Comment: @YotamSalmon, your code outcome I was expecting, Thx. However I was thinking to use a dict to speed up.. any ideas about it?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
output_list = []
for lst in my_list:
    for l in output_list:
        if l[0] == lst[0]:
            for item in lst:
                    if item not in l:
                      l.append(item)
            break
    else:
        output_list.append(lst)
```

Comment: `"green"` gets duped in list 1... does not match example output

Comment: Whoops, didn't see that they didn't want dupes in the list. It's fixed now, though.